# JSON parsing in Python without explicitly accessing keys

Tags: python, json

JSON data:

```
[
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "An ice sculpture",
  "price": 12.50,
 },

 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "A blue mouse",
  "price": 25.50,
 }
]
```

Expected output:

```
id - 2
name - An ice sculpture
price - 12.50
```

Something similar for id = 3.

## Update

What I did so far:

```
content = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
content = content.replace("//" , "").strip() #there is a // at the beginning
obj = json.loads(content)
for obj in content:
    for key, value in obj.items():
        print (obj.key, obj.value)
```

Error:

```
File "test.py", line 22, in get
for key, value in obj.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I've seen mostly data is accessed directly using the attribute keys like `obj[0]["id"]` outputs `2`. Is there any way I can get the expected output without accessing the keys explicitly?

Comment: What is obj? It looks like a list, but you seem to think it's a dictionary

Comment: What do you mean of `without accessing the keys explicitly`?

Comment: @mohammad In `obj[0]["id"]` I have to mention the key "id' to retrieve its value. I want it to be in a generalized form.

Comment: @cricket_007 I've edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of dictionaries. Your code would work, as long as you iterate through the outer list:

```
for obj in my_json_data:
    for key, value in obj.items():
         print (obj.key, obj.value)
```

Comment: Why are you asking me? You were the one that posted it in the question.

Comment: No, I'm getting an error that `str object has no attribute items`. I think there is a data type error. And, I've edited my question with additional code.

Comment: @AlphaQ - you showed the JSON in your question. If you'd like more help, you need to add the URL so we can reproduce the actual problems you're having

Comment: There's no way that this code doesn't work while `my_json_data[0]['id']` does.

Comment: But that shows that your object is a string. So `content[0]["id"]` cannot possibly have worked.

Comment: You're not being clear enough to answer. What is `obj`? In your snippet you've loaded the JSON into `content`.

Comment: `obj` is the loaded JSON from the string `content`. `content` holds the data in string format and I'm loading the string into `obj`.

Comment: You are being totally inconsistent with your variables. You load the JSON to `obj`. So you need to iterate through `obj`, not `content`, and use a different variable for the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
data = [
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "An ice sculpture",
  "price": 12.50,
 },

 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "A blue mouse",
  "price": 25.50,
 }
]

for json_data in data:
    for k, v in json_data.items():
        print('{} - {}'.format(k,v))
```

Comment: how about the print statement where I actually got the format OP requested?